# dump mapping from ES 2.1 to ES 7.2

Tags: elasticsearch

Im new in elasticsearch, but really need help to solve this problem.
I try to migrate all indices and data from ES 2.1.1(port 6200) to ES 7.2.1(port 9200), and when i run this command then problem is coming.
Can anyone help?
Ty

```
Mac$ elasticdump \
>   --input=http://localhost:6200/twitter \
>   --output=http://localhost:9200/twitter \
>   --type=analyzer
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:23 GMT | starting dump
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:24 GMT | got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:56 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 1
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:56 GMT | got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 1)
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:56 GMT | Total Writes: 1
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:38:56 GMT | dump complete

Mac$ elasticdump \
>   --input=http://localhost:6200/twitter \
>   --output=http://localhost:9200/twitter \
>   --type=mapping
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:45 GMT | starting dump
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:45 GMT | got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:46 GMT | Error Emitted => {"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [display_url]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [display_url]"}
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:46 GMT | Error Emitted => {"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [display_url]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [string] declared on field [display_url]"}
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:46 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:39:46 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => [object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the field `display_url` is of type `string` and that has changed to `text` in ES 5.0. So you need to replace all occurrences of `string` to `text` in your mapping before trying to send that to ES 7.

So you need to do it in two steps:

```
Mac$ elasticdump \
>   --input=http://localhost:6200/twitter \
>   --file=twitter-mapping.json \
>   --type=mapping
```

Then change all `string` occurrences to `text`, and then you can send the mapping.

```
Mac$ elasticdump \
>   --file=twitter-mapping.json \
>   --output=http://localhost:9200/twitter \
>   --type=mapping
```

Comment: ty for helping me, this i did waht you said but there is another error comming.